# Change the text color of child div one mouse over

Tags: html, css

I need to change the color of the text which is not the immediate element of the target element.

It is the child of another parent div. How do I target an outer element through css?

In the demo you can see `another text' color changes on mouse over of`div1 span`, likewise I want to change the color of div2 span`

In my code, how can I target the div2's span (not the the div2 coz there will be many other elements inside div 2)?

***PS - Need to target a child element of another parent from another parent element's child element.***

**HTML**

```
<div class="div1">
  <span>hover me</span>
  <div class="another_txt">
  Another text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div2">
<span>How to change this text color on div1 span hover?</span>
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vf8ab8yh/)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use CSS, you have to assign the :hover to .div1 in order to select .div2 in your hover (as you can not select a parent in CSS):

```css
.div1:hover .another_txt {
    color: red;
 }
  
.div1:hover + .div2 span{
    color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <span>hover me</span>
  <div class="another_txt">
  Another text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div2">
<span>How to change this text color on div1 span hover?</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Need to target the child element div1 span to div 2 span

Comment: There is no CSS Parent selector in either CSS2.1 (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching) or CSS3 (https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors). You'll have to use JS in order to select a parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript / JQuery for this. To my knowledge you cannot achieve it in CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="div1">
  <span id="hover">hover me</span>
  <div class="another_txt">
  Another text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div2">
<span id="target">How to change this text color on div1 span hover?</span>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hover").hover(function() {
       $("#target").css("color", "red");
  })
})
```

Here is the live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vf8ab8yh/1/

Comment: Dude, he never wanted to achieve through JS.

Comment: Looking for pure CSS solution

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to wrap the `span` in another wrapper (*you can also not wrap it,your choice*) then use the `~` selector.

The use of `~` is to select all the second element *(`.div2`)* preceded by the first element *(`.newDiv`)*. You can read more from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp).

> The element1~element2 selector matches occurrences of element2 that are preceded by element1.
>
> Both elements must have the same parent, but element2 does not have to be immediately preceded by element1.

```css
.newDiv:hover~.div2>span {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="newDiv"><span>hover me</span></div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="another_txt">
    Another text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div2">
  <span>How to change this text color on div1 span hover?</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To target the span in the `div2` when `div1`is hovered use the following CSS selector:

```
.div1:hover+.div2 span{
  color: pink;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
.div1:hover+.div2 span{
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <span>hover me</span>
  <div class="another_txt">
    Another text
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <span>How to change this text color on div1 span hover?</span>
  <div>Don't change this</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The element1~element2 selector matches occurrences of element2 that are preceded by element1.

Both elements must have the same parent, but element2 does not have to be immediately preceded by element1.

[css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp)

```css
.div1:hover~.div2 {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <span>hover me</span>
  <div class="another_txt">
    Another text
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <span>How to change this text color on div1 span hover?</span>
</div>
```